# Are the partial derivatives of a function increasing in both variables measurable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that is nondecreasing in both variables, i.e. $f(x_1,y_1)\le f(x_2,y_2)$ whenever
$x_1\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y_2$. It is known that the partial derivatives
$\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ exist almost everywhere, but are they Lebesgue measurable?

The one-dimensional version of this problem is well-studied, and it is known that
the restriction of $\partial f/\partial x$ to the set $[0,1]\times\{y\}$ is measurable for any $y$. It is also known that $\partial f/\partial x$ is measurable when restricted to the subset of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ where $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: If $f$ is measurable, then this follows from Theorem 1 of [Measurability of partial derivatives](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-063-02/S0002-9939-1977-0437696-1/) by Moshe and Mizel. How do you establish the existence of partial derivatives without measurability anyways? Is such a function automatically measurable?

Comment: @CameronZwarich: I think $f$ is automatically measurable. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$; we must show that $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is measurable. For each $x \in [0,1]$ define $g(x) = \sup\{y: f(x,y) \leq a\}$. Then $g$ is decreasing, which surely implies that its graph has measure zero, and $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is the region below this graph (measurable) plus some subset of the graph itself (null).

Comment: @NikWeaver Seems like that works. Thanks.

Comment: @CameronZwarich: $\partial _1 f$ and $\partial_2 f$ are also automatically measurable, since they are a.e. limits of incremental quotients, $n(f(x+1/n,y)-f(x,y))$ resp. $n(f(x,y+1/n)-f(x,y))$, which are measurable too.

Comment: @PietroMajer: Ah, it's that simple! Thanks, all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As Nik Weaver's comment points out, your function is automatically measurable. Therefore you can apply Theorem 1 of [Measurability of partial derivatives](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-063-02/S0002-9939-1977-0437696-1/) by Moshe and Mizel.